# Cannot Extract Params from URL

Tags: api, get, yii2

Good Afternoon,

I have a external GET request hitting a controller action but i cannot retrieve the params.

the URL looks like:

```
https://yourway.local/strava/webstatusrep?hub.verify_token=STRAVA&hub.challenge=15f7d1a91c1f40f8a748fd134752feb3&hub.mode=subscribe
```

i have tried using

```
$param1 = $request->getQueryParam('hub.challenge');

or 

 $param = ArrayHelper::getValue(Yii::$app->request->get(), 'hub.challenge');
```

But also in Xdebug i can see they are not sitting in the “queryparams” section.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `.` with `_` in param name when calling Yii2 api:

```
$paramValue = Yii::$app->request->get("hub_challenge");
```